AWS Elastic Beanstalk Environment Health Degraded(env goes to invalid state because of platform update failure) Due to RDS Issues
I am facing a problem where my AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment's health has been degraded automatically. I received the following error messages in the Environment Events log:Failed to deploy configuration.
August 15, 2024 13:07:33 (UTC+5)
ERROR
Rollback of environment Univexch-env failed. Reason: The following resource(s) failed to update: [AWSEBRDSDatabase].
ERROR
Updating RDS database named: awseb-e-i4w84yjffc-stack-awsebrdsdatabase failed. 
Reason: Resource handler returned message: 
"User: arn:aws:sts::14:assumed-role/aws-elasticbeanstalk-service-role/elasticbeanstalk 
is not authorized to perform: rds:ModifyDBInstance on resource: 
arn:aws:rds:us-east-1:141408100488:db:awseb-e-i4w84yjffc-stack-awsebrdsdatabase 
because no identity-based policy allows the rds:ModifyDBInstance action 
(Service: Rds, Status Code: 403, Request ID: 43f16117-cf09-4a3c-b4c7-9f4dfe5e)" 
(RequestToken: 336c4947-d7da-c10b-3360-dabc48cc6, HandlerErrorCode: AccessDenied)
The environment was attempting to modify the RDS database but failed due to an AccessDenied error. It seems that the role aws-elasticbeanstalk-service-role does not have the required permissions to modify the RDS instance.
Additionally, I also noticed this message in the RDS console:
Upgrade required for your databases
You have one or more RDS databases that use RDS Certificate Authorities that have expired or are reaching end-of-life (EOL). After expiry, RDS can no longer accept new connections with these certificates.
I suspect that the expiring RDS Certificate Authorities might also be contributing to the degraded environment health.
My Questions:

How can I resolve the AccessDenied error for the aws-elasticbeanstalk-service-role to ensure it has the appropriate permissions to modify the RDS instance?

Could the expiring RDS Certificate Authorities cause the environment's health to degrade?

Are there any specific steps I need to follow to ensure my environment health recovers once the permissions and certificates are updated?


Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
What I've Tried:

I attempted to restart the app server, but it failed, saying the instance is not in  "available." state

I've avoided making any changes to the RDS instance because there is a lot of important data in the database, and I don’t want to risk any potential data loss.


What I Expect:
I want to understand the root cause of this issue. The environment has been stable for a year, and this is the first time I’ve encountered any problems. How can I safely debug and resolve these issues without risking data loss? I suspect the expiring RDS certificates could be part of the problem, but I am not certain if they are causing the environment health to degrade.

after a bit of research, i am able to recover my env without rebuilding or cloning it, here are some generic steps to consider

Go to CloudFormation and look for failed stack(for my case Platform
updates failed due to RDS permission issue)

Update the required permissions in IAM, go to roles and
aws-elasticbeanstalk-service-role, and update the required
permissions(RDS permissions in my case)

Back to cloudformation and try to Roll it back into
"UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE" state now as the permission has been
granted now you can try to update it again, in my case it is
Updated, and stack status is turned into "UPDATE_COMPLETE"

Now we need AWS support team help to Make our environment
available(NOTE: You can contact also support team when stack status
is "UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE") here are some resources that might
help also


https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/cloudformation-update-rollback-failed
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/troubleshooting.html#troubleshooting-errors-update-rollback-failed
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-updating-stacks-continueupdaterollback.html
https://repost.aws/questions/QURbQndArQR2als7V8K7-2cw/update-rollback-complete-error-after-changing-ami-in-parameter-store

go to the IAM console, find the aws-elasticbeanstalk-service-role, and edit the policy to include the following permission:
{
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Action": "rds:ModifyDBInstance",
  "Resource": "arn:aws:rds:us-east-1:141408100488:db:awseb-e-i4w84yjffc-stack-awsebrdsdatabase"
}



i tried that already, i cannot restart app server, cannot change configurations , because it says environment is not in valid state, cannot deploy new version or rollback to previous one

can you check the eb logs and show  the error there @Maverick

nothing wrong in logs, i have checked last 100 and bundle also, everything looks fine, elb health check is good, nothing is wrong in logs, except some errors in events, which i have shared, as per i have explored , yesterday there was a platform update which fails and it rollback to previous version, nothing else is there

Env goes into invalid state because platform updates failed and unable to rollback to previous state, i tried to rollback manually via CloudFormation and it is now in "UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE" state, but still env is in Invalid state

We have the same issue, the certificate was updated a few days ago, but now we have the same issue with permissions.

certificates for RDS? right? the issue in my side is not from RDS , at least not for now, my environment goes to invalid state, after platform update failure, and now i cannot redeploy , update configurations or restart the app server

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
